# Flutter - Error: Unable to create dart snapshot for flutter tool

Tags: flutter, dart

When I run `flutter change channel` or `flutter doctor`, the CMD show me this:

```
C:\Users\MyUser>flutter doctor -v
Checking Dart SDK version...

Building flutter tool...

Running pub upgrade...

/C:/src/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/lib/src/aot.dart:144:5: Warning: Must explicitly return a value from a non-void function.
    return;
    ^
```

When I run:

```
git clean -xfd

git pull

flutter doctor
```

The CDM show me this:

```
fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
```

How can I solve it? Thank you

Comment: I thnk its `flutter channel` your-channel here  try `flutter channel master`  and see if the error fixed itself

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Had the same issue...Copied the flutter_tools from flutter download and replaced with the same folder in my installation then ran flutter doctor from command in administrator mode.
Funny the issue started 3 days ago for me too.

Answer (score 3):

1.Go the Flutter install directory and please run (in cmd)

git clean -xfd

git stash save --keep-index

git stash drop

git pull

2.and restart your computer
  then run

flutter doctor

3.then go to your project path run

flutter packages get

flutter run

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem yesterday, i tired to run

git clean -xfd

git pull

flutter doctor

in cmd and i kept getting:

fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git

eventually i gave up and i deleted the old flutter sdk directory from my PC as well as the path from Enviroment Variables and i downloded the new sdk and setup flutter again and now it's running fine

https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install

Answer (score 0):

On windows, delete flutter folder C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Pub
This is the flutter temp/cache folder and may contain outdated versions of the libraries

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately none of the given solution so far works for me..

I had to the following steps, which was the only solution for me:

- delete the whole flutter folder
- extract (or copy) it from the zip-file to your installation directory (in my case I just downloaded the latest flutter version, because I didn't have access to the previous downloaded zip-file anymore)
- open the IDE in the installation directory (or open the associated project)
- run flutter pub get